# reverse urls for Django class based view

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to do something like:

in urls.py:

```
...
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', VideoDetailView.as_view(), name='video_detail', kwargs={'foo:''})
...
```

in views.py

```
..
HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('video_detail', kwargs={'pk': id, 'foo':'bar'}))
...
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I get a 
Reverse for 'video_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 13240L, 'foo': 'bar}' not found.

However this does work:

```
....
HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('video_detail', kwargs={'pk': id}))
...
```

ie. removing foo: bar from the reverse call. What's the correct way to do this and pass in extra arguments in the reverse url?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`reverse` is a function that creates URL.

Because You have specified only `pk` pattern in your URL patterns, you can only use `pk` as argument to `reverse` (it really would not make sense to add `foo` since the generated url would be exactly the same for any `foo` value). You can add `foo` to URL pattern or create multiple named urls, ie:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', VideoDetailView.as_view(), name='video_detail', kwargs={'foo':''})
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', VideoDetailView.as_view(), name='video_detail2', kwargs={'foo':'bar'})
```

or

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<foo>\w+)/$', VideoDetailView.as_view(), name='video_detail')
```